# Problems with UIDevice properties and NSLog

Tags: iphone, properties, nslog, uidevice

I've been trying to log device parameters using [[UIDevice currentDevice] ...] and NSLog. I always get the same warning despite trying different ways to go about it.

The warning I get is:

```
Passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' from incompatible pointer type
```

Here are all my attempts:

## 1:

```
NSString *UDID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
    NSString *deviceName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
    NSString *deviceModel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];

    NSLog("\nDevice UDID: %@\nDevice Name: %@\nDevice Mode:%@\n",UDID, deviceName, deviceModel);
```

## 2:

```
NSString *UDID = (NSString*)[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
    NSString *deviceName = (NSString*)[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
    NSString *deviceModel = (NSString*)[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];

    NSLog("\nDevice UDID: %@\nDevice Name: %@\nDevice Mode:%@\n",UDID, deviceName, deviceModel);
```

## 3:

```
NSString *UDID = [NSString stringWithFormat:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]];
    NSString *deviceName = [NSString stringWithFormat:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]];
    NSString *deviceModel = [NSString stringWithFormat:[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]];

    NSLog("\nDevice UDID: %@\nDevice Name: %@\nDevice Mode:%@\n",UDID, deviceName, deviceModel);
```

## 4:

```
NSLog("\nDevice UDID: %@\nDevice Name: %@\nDevice Mode:%@\n",[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier], [[UIDevice currentDevice] name], [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]);
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use an NSString as the first argument to NSLog
For example

```
NSLog(@"\nDevice UDID: %@\nDevice Name: %@\nDevice Mode:%@\n",UDID, deviceName, deviceModel);
```

Notice the '@' before the start of the string

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for your good eye.... I feel sooo stupid now lol

Answer (score 2):

`NSLog` takes an NSString as the format string, not a `const char*`. Prepend your string with a `@`.

i.e.:

```
NSLog(@"\nDevice UDID: %@\nDevice Name: %@\nDevice Mode:%@\n", ....
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSLog` requires an `NSString` as its format argument. You should be calling `NSLog` like so:

```
NSLog(@"\nDevice UDID: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]);
```

Note the "@" at the beginning - that's a constant `NSString` reference. You're using bare C strings.